# 502 bad gateway nginx

Tags: php, nginx

При импорте xml получаю данную ошибку, когда в xml более 100 к записей. 
Подскажите , какие конфиги надо подкрутить на сервере, чтобы увеличить параметры ?

Comment: Для начала бы узнать на что он ругается. К сожалению, экстрасенсы в отпуске и вам придётся самому заглянуть в логи и посмотреть ошибку. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, записав в него ошибку.

Comment: Увеличьте допустимый размер файла при отправке через форму